# What are the parameters and how to add it in plugins of cronicle?

Tags: python, cron, cronicle

`Cronicle` is similar to `cronjobs`
Here is GitHub link: https://github.com/jhuckaby/Cronicle#Plugins%20Tab

But I don't know how to add parameters in plugins.

It says

```
Parameters are passed to your Plugin via JSON, and as environment variables.
For example, you can use this to customize the PATH variable, if your Plugin requires it.
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Python

```py
import json,sys

path = json.load(sys.stdin)["params"]["path"]
```

Cronicle takes json as input